# A script that places HDD location eg.sda into a variable

Tags: linux, bash, redhat

What I'm trying to do via command line is have a script take a newly connected HDD and put its device location eg. sda, sdb, sdc etc into a variable i can use.
I've tried:

tail -f /var/log/messages | grep GB/

Which take the line with "GB/" which has the device location.

But i can not manipulate line down using "sed" or anything equivalent as i don't know how to exit the command above once it have found the most recent, relevant information and i also cant get that information into a position to manipulate it.

I have tried the > and >> to output to a file but that didn't work and have also tried putting the above code in brackets and redirecting that which also didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear when you would be doing this, like if it's just after you "know" that a new HDD has been connected.

What you could do is capture the output of "ls -1d /sys/block/sd*" before, and then again after, and diff them, which would give the added device.

Comment: Basically this script will be involved putting something onto a HDD. What I wanted to happen is the script asks the use to put in the HDD then pauses until the HDD has been inserted and saves the device name into a variable to be used in the rest of the script.

Answer (score 0):

This works on my machine,

```
$ HDD=$(dmesg | grep blocks | cut -f3 -d\[ | cut -f1 -d\] | tail -n1)
$ echo $HDD
sdk
```

Comment: Thanks and that did work but it was: HDD=$(dmesg | grep blocks | cut -f2 -d\[ | cut -f1 -d\] | tail -n1)